# IAM Policy to deny snapshot creation of particular volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I need to restrict access from EC2 Volume,

```
       {
        "Sid": "Stmt1487944277000",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:035438026151:volume/vol-volume-id"]
```

but when i try to create snapshot, Snapshot created easily without any error of that volume, and when i try to delete that volume, i got error that i have does not any rights. So what is the possible solution to restrict access of that volume ?